# How to hide php file extension from url from all files?

Tags: php

I have a lot of php files, but I stuck in this that I want to hide php extension from url in for all files without the need to edit my code. 
Another problem is that the website use $_GET to caught many parameters from links, headers, forms, is there a way to hide parameters from url or at least to change how it looks without effecting the website functionality.

I tried this but didnot work :

```
 Options -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?]+)\.php\?pid=([0-9]+)
 RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?]+)\.php(\ |$)
 RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([0-9]+)$ /$1.php?pid=$2 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: you will still need to change anchors hrefs in your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code in *.htaccess* file

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks.